# The Salesforce CLI Binary URL installs older version of Salesforce CLI. How to update Salesforce CLI to the latest version?

Tags: salesforcedx-cli, cli

I have been installing the Salesforce CLI in my Circle CI scripts using the below

`mkdir sfdx`

`wget -qO- https://developer.salesforce.com/media/salesforce-cli/sfdx-linux-amd64.tar.xz | tar xJ -C sfdx --strip-components 1`

`./sfdx/install`

The version of the CLI upon running `sfdx --version` is `7.94.3-a4e7c7955b`. The latest version is `7.98`

How do I get the latest version of the CLI?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The URL to get the latest version of the Salesforce CLI is changed to **https://developer.salesforce.com/media/salesforce-cli/sfdx/channels/stable/sfdx-linux-x64.tar.xz**

Previously it was **https://developer.salesforce.com/media/salesforce-cli/sfdx-linux-amd64.tar.xz**

Also, the new URL no longer contains the install script. The updated documentation can be found [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.230.0.sfdx_setup.meta/sfdx_setup/sfdx_setup_install_cli.htm).

The updated Circle CI script is as below

`mkdir sfdx`

`wget https://developer.salesforce.com/media/salesforce-cli/sfdx/channels/stable/sfdx-linux-x64.tar.xz`

`tar xJf sfdx-linux-x64.tar.xz -C ./sfdx --strip-components 1`

`echo 'export PATH=./sfdx/bin/:$PATH' >> $BASH_ENV`

`source $BASH_ENV`

The other way to install Salesforce CLI in CI is to simply use the **npm**

`sudo npm install --global sfdx-cli@latest`